# Py2exe Pywin32 Error

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe, pywin32

Py2exe perfectly converts python scripts to windows executable, unless the file includes pywin32. In that case, it shows a RuntimeError:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

All other python files are having no trouble with py2exe.
So, Is there any way to make py2exe work with pywin32?

Note: I've tried increasing recursion depth limit, it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you post the full traceback? Also what value did you try to increase the recursionlimit to? And where? *pywin32* has ~750 files and ~100 dirs. Are you using other "large" packages? Also, could you post the code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @CristiFati I increased recursion limit to 5000. It didn't work. I tried 10000 but the program stopped. I'm not building anything heavy but a simple script that will use pywebview to create a window to show a website.